# events on multiple calendar it is not taking the id of selected tab

Tags: javascript, laravel, fullcalendar

Hi there I have this calendar can someone help me how can I display data of proper agent id  this foreach is showing the same for each calendar is it possible to make a query or something

```js
<script>

$(function() {
   
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var agent_id = $(e.target).attr("agent_idja") // activated tab
 

  $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

    // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
    $(this).data('event', {
      title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
      stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
    });

    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    $(this).draggable({
      zIndex: 999,
      revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
      revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
    });

  });
 
 

  $('#calendar' + agent_id).fullCalendar({
 

    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
     events: [
 

  @foreach($appointments_agents as $appointmenti)
  
            
                {
                    title : '{{ $appointmenti->agent_id }}',
                    start : '{{ $appointmenti->start_at }}',

                   
                }, 
                
              
                @endforeach

      ],
    
    drop: function(event) {
         var apo_id = $(this).attr('apo_id');
   
          console.log(agent_id);

            $.ajax({

                method: "POST",
                url: "{{ url('/change-agent') }}",
                data: {
                    _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    agent_id: agent_id,
                    appointment_id:apo_id
                    
 
                },
                success: function () {

                  console.log("ok");
                  
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            });
      // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
      if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
        $(this).remove();
      }
    }

  });






});

});


</script>
```

```html
            <div class="container-fluid">



  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Agents</h4>
                               
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
                             
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs customtab" role="tablist">
                                     @foreach($agents as $key=> $agent)
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link " data-toggle="tab" agent_idja="{{$agent->id}}" href="#agent{{$agent->id}}" id="tab{{$key}}" role="tab">   <div class="user-profile dropdown m-t-20">
                                     <div class="user-pic">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('app/assets/images/users/1.jpg') }}" alt="users" class="rounded-circle img-fluid" />
                                </div></div> <span class="hidden-xs-down">{{$agent->name}}</span></a> </li>

       @endforeach

</ul>


 <div class="p-20">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="card">
                             <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3 border-right p-r-0">
                                         <div class="card-body border-bottom">
                                            <h4 class="card-title m-t-10">Drag & Drop Appointments </h4>
                                        </div>
                                          <div class="card-body">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-12">
<div id='external-events'>
  @foreach($appointments as $appointment)

    <div class='fc-event' apo_id="{{$appointment->id}}"  >  {{$appointment->firstname}}  <br>{{$appointment->start_at}}</div><br>    
     @endforeach
  
    <p>
        <input type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' checked/>
        <label for='drop-remove'>remove after drop</label>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div><div class="col-lg-9">

<div class="tab-content tabcontent-border">
        <?php $i=1; ?>
 @foreach($agents as $key=> $agent)
    <div class="tab-pane agent tabs{{$key}}" id="agent{{$agent->id}}"  agent_id="{{$agent->id}}"   role="tabpanel">{{$agent->id}}
        
               <div class="card-body b-l calender-sidebar">

                    <div id='calendar-container'>
                        <div id='calendar{{$agent->id}}' class="calendar" agent-id="{{{$agent->id}}}"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <?php $i++; ?>
@endforeach
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>



</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
             
        </div>
```

So this is how it is shown
[image]

As you can see here on the attached screenshot I managed to change the calendars with tabs and when I switch it shows the calendar for that agent id, but for the events it does not work I dont know why  does someone have an idea what should I do..? I tried inside the foreach of appointment to use a condition like if $appointment->agent_id == agent_id but does not work

Comment: does all your agent_id variables starts from 0?

Comment: they start from 1 they are saved on database from number 1

Comment: it's not clear, in the PHP are you making multiple calendars by looping this JS code? If so then you need to make it so that this indicates the specific agent who the calendar is for, then your inner foreach can make use of that to restrict the events it loops through.

Comment: P.S. you could also consider using the Scheduler plugin: https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler so you can put all the agents into one calendar - each agent can be listed as a "resource". Depending on the nature of your organisation you might have to buy a [license](https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/license) of course but it might be worth considering in order to simplify your code.

Comment: I am making multiple calendars depending of how many agents I have so foreach agent I have calendars, and down to the javascript code  I have foreach events,  and that #calendar id  is calendar + agent_id so it will be for that particular agent, but  events  are not showing for that particular agent I dont know how to manipulate the foreach  of events for that particular agent, I am sorry If I am not very understandble I dont know how to explain

Comment: Ok I see. The problem is that you don't know the agent ID until the code runs in the JavaScript to click on the tab. Yet you are generating the events using PHP on the server before the calendar is ever created. The logic is backwards. Since you are re-using the same calendar code for every agent, then I think you need to make fullCalendar fetch the specific agent's events via AJAX each time - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function to explain the two approaches you can take.

Comment: P.S. It also seems pointless to re-create your external-events every time the tab changes, it will always produce the same result. Instead I think you could move this outside your "shown" tab callback

Comment: I really appreciate that you are trying to help me, but I am new on coding and I tried what you said I tried putting  this: $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

  events: {
    url: '/myfeed.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      custom_param1: 'something',
      custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
    },
    color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
    textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
  }

});

Comment: And to url I put my controller but it alerts the error, I dont know what I should do to the controller I have the date on eloquent  I dont know how to fetch them.. :/

Comment: well what actual error did you get? Check your browser's console and/or your PHP logs to see. And what does myfeed.php do? It's very hard to advise about code I cannot see. What it _needs_ to do is return the appropriate event data as an array in JSON format. And you need to supply `agent_id` as a parameter to send to it